# Function with IFormattable parameter won't accept a String

Tags: c#, .net, iformattable

I have a function where I processed a string input.

```
    public string Foo(string text)
    {
        // do stuff with text and
        // return processed string
    }
```

I was calling this from a lot of places where I was converting a guid to a string like this:

```
string returnValue = Foo(bar.ToString());
```

What I actually wanted was to accept as an input any object type that could be converted to a string. So I tried modifying the function as follows:

```
    public string Foo(IFormattable text)
    {
        var textAsString = text.ToString();
        // do stuff with textAsString 
        // and return processed string
    }
```

This means all my calls are simpler:

```
string returnValue = Foo(bar);
```

It works for all object types that have a .ToString method; Except strings :)

If I try passing a string to the function I get the following compile error:

```
Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.IFormattable'
```

Which seems really odd because String HAS a ToString() method.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, [`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) doesn't implement `IFormattable`.

If the documentation isn't enough for you:

```
object x = "a string";
Console.WriteLine(x is IFormattable); // False
```

Given that [`ToString()` is declared on `object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx), why not just have:

```
public string Foo(object text)
{
    var textAsString = text.ToString();
    // do stuff with textAsString 
    // and return processed string
}
```

Indeed, the [`ToString()` method declared by `IFormattable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring.aspx) isn't the one you were trying to call anyway - you weren't passing a format string or a format provider.

Additionally:

> Which seems really odd because String HAS a ToString() method.

Interfaces aren't duck-typed. Just because a type has all the members required by an interface doesn't mean that it implements the interface.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `IFormatable` does not implment `.ToString()`, it only implments [`.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). With that knowledge in hand, if you still want to use `IFormatable` the easiest way to handle this is just use overloads for your methods.

```
public string Foo(IFormattable text, string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
{
    return Foo(text.ToString(format, formatProvider));
}

public string Foo(IFormattable text, string format)
{
    return Foo(text.ToString(format, null));
}

public string Foo(string text)
{
    // do stuff with text and
    // return processed string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`String` does not implement `IFormattable`, but your code does not use it either. You can create a wrapper class for a `string` to be used in scenarios where `IFormattable` is needed, like this:

```
public class FormattableString : IFormattable {
    private readonly string str;
    public FormattableString(string str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
    public string ToString() {
        return str;
    }
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider) {
        // You can add special code here to format the value of your string
        // as directed by the format passed into the method.
        return str;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this class as follows:

```
string returnValue = Foo(new FormattableString(bar));
```

Comment: I think the argument-less ToString() is unnecessary (and if present should have "override").
But otherwise this is exactly what I wanted, thanks!